# What is the value of $\lim_{x\to-1} \frac{\log(x^2+2x+2)}{(x+1)^2}$?

Tags: limits, solution-verification

*This question came in the Chittagong University admission exam 2013-14*

Q) What is the value of $\lim_{x\to-1} \frac{\log(x^2+2x+2)}{(x+1)^2}$?

(a) 5

(b) 2

(c) 1

(d) 0.5

**My attempt:**

They didn't specify the base of the $\log$. I'll assume that the base is 10.

$$\lim_{x\to-1} \frac{\log(x^2+2x+2)}{(x+1)^2}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to-1} \frac{\log((x+1)^2+1)}{(x+1)^2}$$

If $x\to -1$, then $(x+1)\to 0$, then $(x+1)^2\to 0$.

$$=\lim_{(x+1)^2\to0} \frac{\log((x+1)^2+1)}{(x+1)^2}$$

Let $(x+1)^2=z$.

$$=\lim_{z\to0} \frac{\log(z+1)}{z}$$

Let us apply L'Hopital's rule:

$$=\lim_{z\to0} \frac{\frac{1}{(z+1)\ln(10)}\cdot 1}{1}$$

$$=\lim_{z\to0} \frac{1}{(z+1)\ln(10)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\ln(10)}\text{(Ans.)}$$

**My Questions:**

1. Did I do the math correctly?
2. Why isn't $\frac{1}{\ln(10)}$ listed among the four options? *(Maybe the base of the log is e, not 10*)

Comment: I'm sure it's meant to be log to the base $e$ and the answer is $1$.

Comment: Yes, in mathematics (and sometimes even in engineering), when I see "$\log$" I assume that the base is $e,$ unless otherwise clued in. So, [$1$ is the correct answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit+of+%5Cfrac%7B%5Clog%28x%5E2%2B2x%2B2%29%7D%7B%28x%2B1%29%5E2%7D+as+x+approaches+-1). Anyway, since your computed answer isn't among the offered options, wouldn't it have been quicker to simply rework the problem using base $e$ than to create a post?

Comment: [Meaning of log](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/369056/21813) and [Should we stop differentiating between ln and log?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/17605/372)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that:
$$\log(1+f(x))\,\,\sim\,\,f(x)$$
When $f(x)\to 0$ and $x\to x_0$. So:
$$x^2+2x+2=1+(x+1)^2$$
And:
$$\lim_{x\to-1} \frac{\log(x^2+2x+2)}{(x+1)^2}=\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{\log(1+(x+1)^2)}{(x+1)^2}\,\,\sim\,\,\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{(x+1)^2}{(x+1)^2}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x\to-1} \frac{\ln((x+1)^2+1)}{(x+1)^2}$$
Let $z=(x+1)^2$
then $$L=\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(1+z)}{z}$$
By L-Hospital
$$L=\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}  \frac{1}{1+z}=1$$

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: In you steps change $\log 10$ to $\log e=\ln e=1$

Comment: Yes, if we use $\log_{10}$, we get $\frac{1}{\ln 10}$. That isn't listed among the options. So, the base that the question meant is $\log_e$ or $\ln$.